# how to get root document fields of collection in firestore android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the document fields of the root collection in android **firestore**

my database structure in firestore is

```
collection
      documents-->root fields
               collection
                          documents-->fields
```

now i want to get root fields. How to do that in android firestore?

```
firestore.collection("Players").orderBy("deptName").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    //model class
                    Example example=document.toObject(Example.class);
                    exampleList.add(example);

                }


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+exampleList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code gets the documents from the root `Players` collection. What is the problem with this code? What results does it give? And what results do you expect/want to get?

Comment: What is wrong with this code? Please also add a screenshot of your database schema and please also responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

[image]   use this line  document.getId();

```
firestore.collection("Players").orderBy("deptName").get()

.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    //model class
                    Example example=document.toObject(Example.class);
 example.setDocID(document.getId());
                    exampleList.add(example);

                }


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+exampleList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java_2